# Update params of state without reloading controller

Tags: angularjs

I want the controller to not reload whenever the query parameter changes. I have tried setting `reloadOnSearch` as false still the controller reloads on changing the `stateparam`.

Here is the code I am using to achieve the results.

```
 $stateProvider
            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
                controller:'loginCtrl'
            })
            .state('layout', {
                url: '/layout',
                templateUrl: 'templates/layout.html',
                controller:'layoutCtrl'
            })
            .state('main', {
                url: '/main',
                templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
                abstract:true,
                controller:'mainCtrl'               
            })
            .state('main.welcome', {
                url: '/welcome/:id',
                templateUrl: 'templates/welcome.html',
                reloadOnSearch : false,
                controller:'greetingCtrl'

            })
```

For example when the state changes from `/main/welcome/1` to `/main/welcome/2`the controller reloads which I don't want it to.

Comment: Version of `ui-router`?

Comment: @tasseKATT  Version is 1.0.0alpha0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **ui-router** 1.0.0 you can use dynamic parameters:

> Dynamic parameters (the replacement for reloadOnSearch) can be
>   declared in a params block in a state definition like so: params; {
>   fooParam: { dynamic: true } }. When a dynamic parameter changes, it
>   does not cause the state to be reloaded. A controller/component
>   callback uiOnParamsChanged may be used to be notified of parameter
>   changes.

For example:

```
.state('main.welcome', {
  url: '/welcome/:id',
  params: {
    id: {
      dynamic: true
    }
  },
  templateUrl: 'templates/welcome.html',
  controller: 'greetingCtrl'
})
```

**Demo:** http://run.plnkr.co/uGARJoK2zxGVa2VL/#/main/welcome/1